# Errors when integrating reactive-record with react-rails

Tags: react.rb

I'm having trouble adding `reactive-record` to my project.

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'

gem 'bootstrap-sass' #, '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.1.0'
end

gem 'pg'

gem 'reactive-ruby', '~> 0.7.28'
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'opal'
gem 'opal-browser'
gem 'opal-rails', '~> 0.8.0'
gem 'opal-jquery'     # a clean interface to jQuery from your ruby code

gem 'reactive-router' # a basic SPA router

# gem 'reactive-record'

# ... additional Rails boilerplate below ...
```

When I run the application as-is, it renders the React component just fine. When I uncomment `gem 'reactive-record'`, I get a `NoMethodError` in my controller: `undefined method 'path' for nil:NilClass`. Here is my simple controller:

**home_controller.rb:**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render_component
  end
end
```

`render_component` is the line that triggers the error.

Any clue what the problem is? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I've been troubleshooting for two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installation of reactrb and reactiverecord has been proven more difficult than it should have before.

That's why I created a generator to install everything: https://github.com/loicboutet/reactive-rails-generator

You should be able to get up and running by adding to your gem file : 

`gem 'reactive_rails_generator'`

Then do a `bundle install``

and finally : 
`rails g reactrb:install --all
bundle update`

Will install you reactrb, reactive-record and reactive-router.